# How to View your Virtual Fake Monitor?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, vnc

So I manage to create a virtual fake monitor (number 2) in Windows7. I even tried VLC media player to stream and view it but it seems so slow. any other suggestions? i also tried vnc, but some of them required internet (i want it through lan only for fast control) or sometimes it shows all your monitor.

Comment: VNC does not required Internet, LAN connection is fine.

Comment: which vnc do you prefer? i used tightvnc, but the framerate is kinda low and i can't set it to show monitor 2 only.